# Load image dataset in Google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a folder in my Google drive with 300 images, and I need to read them. I'm doing it individually that way:

```
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Unaerp/5º Ano/1º Semestre/Proces. Sinais e Imagem/Final/frutas_dataset/'
img1 = cv.imread(path + '001.bmp')
```

For doing this for 300 images, my professor said to use a `For` loop. How can I do this?

I tried to use

```
for i in range (0,300):
```

but didn't work, does anyone knows how to help?

Comment: you haven't asked your for loop to do anything ... expand that part of the question and we'll be able to help.

Comment: I put all my code inside the for, but it doesnt run

Comment: can you amend your question and show that ... also show the error messages that you got.  We'll be able to help after you do that ... also, just use dummy data if your real data is confidential.